# Excel data entry with date matching plus move to another sheet after table run out

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and would like to learn by creating expense database, How do I transferring and making monthly database?

If dashboard date is matching to Aug17 column A, move data from dashboard to Aug17 respective row. If possible, I would like it to search dashboard date to all worksheet and move data to respective row if matching found. Thanks in advance. 
[DashBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rxv7.png)

[Aug17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtGfm.png)

Comment: That's good, Have  you tried/code anything?

Comment: So, you want to copy the range Worksheets("Dashboard).Range("A5:J5") to Worksheets("Aug17").Range("A17:J17") ?

Comment: yes, if the date match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to my questions in the comments here's code that does what you asked.  Notice that the final `msgbox` will never be encountered if the date is found.  Hopefully you will be able to adjust this code to suit your needs once you understand it.

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range, dashSh As Worksheet, dashR As Range, sh As Worksheet
Dim mo As String, yr As String
Set dashSh = Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set dashR = dashSh.Range("A5:J5")
mo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(dashR.Columns(1), "mmm")
yr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(dashR.Columns(1), "yy")
Set sh = Worksheets(mo & yr)
sh.Activate
Set r = sh.Range("A5")
While r <> ""
  If r = dashR.Columns(1) Then
    r.Select
    dashR.Copy
    sh.Paste
    End
  End If
  Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
MsgBox ("date not found")
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have "13-Aug-17" in cell A5 of the Dashboard sheet, then mo="Aug" and yr="17" should be the result.  Then, if you have a sheet named "Aug17" then worksheets(mo & yr) should reference that sheet and set sh=worksheets(mo & yr) should set the sh variable to that worksheet

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out and deleted the comment. Sorry about that. But I got one question. It only goes to A17. I set to Dashboard A5 as "=today". So I try to change the A5 date to 14 Aug 17 and key in. The problem is data only goes to A17. Not stepping down one row.

Comment: I think you're saying you want to enter different dates into A5 and then have the row copied to the proper date on the Aug17 sheet?

Comment: Yes. exactly. Thanks for patience.

Comment: I've now adjusted the code to do what you've asked.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. I will learn your codes. Thank you so much.